# Python Investing Program Error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried making a simple "investing game". But for some reason the variable cash still says 1000 after the "investment". I also want to make this game continuous. Like the player can keep playing it and gaining/losing cash. The program is below! Thanks!

```
import sys
import random
print "INVEST"
cash = 1000
highlow = ["h", "l"]
percentrand = random.randint(1,99)
percentup = percentrand/100 + 1
percentdown = percentrand/100 - 1
randomhighlow = random.choice(highlow)
print "You have 1000$ on you now."
investquit = raw_input("Invest or quit?")
if investquit.lower() == "quit":
    quit()
elif investquit.lower() == "invest":
    if randomhighlow == "h":
    cash == cash*percentup
    print str(cash) + ",up," + str(percentrand) + "%"
if randomhighlow == "l":
    cash == cash*percentdown
    print str(cash) + ",down," + str(percentrand) + "%"
```

Comment: Typo. `==` is for compare. `=` is for assignment. Voting to close for typo.

Comment: elcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a loop to run the program multiple times. Furthermore, in python 2.7 dividing two ints will produce another int, not a float. That is where your main issue is because that is causing percent up or down to always be 1.

So you should be doing this:

```
percentrand = float(random.randint(1,99))
percentup = percentrand/100.0 + 1
percentdown = percentrand/100.0 - 1
randomhighlow = random.choice(highlow)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems. Other answers and comments cover most of them, but I'll combine them into one answer.

First, you're using integer division when you should be using floating point division. This would work in Python 3.x, but since you've tagged it 2.7 it's different:

```
percentup = percentrand/100.0 + 1
```

Same with the down, except you've subtracted 1 instead of subtracting *from* 1:

```
percentdown = 1 - percentrand/100.0
```

Then you're using the wrong operator to assign `cash`:

```
cash = cash*percentup
```

And you have incorrect indentation in the code as you've posted it.

Finally, you need a loop to keep playing:

```
while True:
```

This seems to work:

```
import sys
import random
print "INVEST"
cash = 1000
highlow = ["h", "l"]

while True:
    percentrand = random.randint(1,99)
    percentup = percentrand/100.0 + 1
    percentdown = 1 - percentrand/100.0
    randomhighlow = random.choice(highlow)
    print "You have $" + str(cash) + " on you now."
    investquit = raw_input("Invest or quit?")
    if investquit.lower() == "quit":
        break
    elif investquit.lower() == "invest":
        if randomhighlow == "h":
            cash = cash*percentup
            print str(cash) + ",up," + str(percentrand) + "%"
        if randomhighlow == "l":
            cash = cash*percentdown
            print str(cash) + ",down," + str(percentrand) + "%"
print 'Thanks for playing!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Double equals `==` is a comparison operator while a single equals `=` is assignment.

In your case to have the cash value update you want

```
cash = cash * percentup
```

(and percentdown accordingly).

To have the game play infinitely, or until a certain condition (i.e. cash > 0) you can surround the whole thing in a while loop, such as

```
while cash > 0:
  percentrand = float(random.randint(1,99))
  [.. rest of code ...]
```

**edit**: as Ryan rightly mentions, you'd want `percentrand = float(random.randint(1,99))` to make sure your division result is not an integer.